# How to format the number when it has atleast thousand unit

Tags: c#

Using the below code I am formatting the double number with group seperator like if the number is 5000, it should display like 5,000 and if the number is only 5 it should display only 5 but here its displaying 05 how can I avoid this?

```
double doubleNumTest = 5;
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#NFormatString) with zero fractional digits; `N0`:

```
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("N0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("#,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format string that you are using is telling it to print the leading zero's, try using the `#` instead of the `0`.

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx)

> "0"    Zero placeholder   Replaces the zero with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, zero appears in the result string.
>
> "#"   Digit placeholder  Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Digit placeholder**:

> Replaces the "#" symbol with the corresponding digit if one is
>   present; otherwise, no digit appears in the result string.
>
> More information: [The "#" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierD).

```
double doubleNumTest = 5;
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

double doubleNumTest = 500;
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

double doubleNumTest = 50000;
string str = doubleNumTest.ToString("#,#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Output:

> 5 
>   500 
>   50,000

See here for the [custom numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) that can be passed to this method.